Jq fails and shows no output on SSE endpoint through curl
Working example with Jq
echo 'data:{"id":"66fc29f995e5b148fe5c7f7d","summary":"Balans: 305.37","level":"info","date":"2024-10-01T16:57:29.873+00:00"}' | sed 's/data://g' | jq '.summary'

Even with new line at the end
echo 'data:{"id":"66fc29f995e5b148fe5c7f7d","summary":"Balans: 305.37","level":"info","date":"2024-10-01T16:57:29.873+00:00"}
' | sed 's/data://g'  | jq '.summary'

Output (success)
"Balans: 305.37"
Not working example with Curl (and SSE endpoint)
curl -N --http2 -H "Accept:text/event-stream" --silent https://my_domain/stream/OyP1cEC3N7BTQrCsm3AHrTFAj5F5VKCH/notifications | sed 's/data://g' | jq '.summary'

This shows no output! My question is: why is this not working?
The following line does however show an output:
Working example with Curl (and SSE endpoint), without jq at end
anon@galliumos:~/Bureaublad$ curl -N --http2 -H "Accept:text/event-stream" --silent https://my_domain/stream/OyP1cEC3N7BTQrCsm3AHrTFAj5F5VKCH/notifications | sed 's/data://g'
{"id":"66fc310d95e5b148fe5c7f8d","summary":"Balans: 305.37","level":"info","date":"2024-10-01T17:27:41.679+00:00"}


The response on my SSE endpoint looks like this, and is working:
data:{"id":"66fc310d95e5b148fe5c7f8d","summary":"Balans: 305.37","level":"info","date":"2024-10-01T17:27:41.679+00:00"}

data:{"id":"66fc310d95e5b148fe5c7f8a","summary":"Balans: 305.37","level":"info","date":"2024-10-01T17:27:41.679+00:00"}

... more records here ...


Update with local SSE test server using NodeJS
This provides a sample SSE endpoint on localhost port 3000.

Create a file named server.js and add the code
Run server with: node server.js

const http = require('http');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  // Server-sent events endpoint
  if (req.url === '/events') {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
      ...(req.httpVersionMajor === 1 && { 'Connection': 'keep-alive' })
    });

    const refreshRate = 1000; // in milliseconds
    return setInterval(() => {
      const data = '{"id":"66fc310d95e5b148fe5c7f8d","summary":"Balans: 305.37","level":"info","date":"2024-10-01T17:27:41.679+00:00"}';
      const message = `data:${data}\n\n`;
      res.write(message);
    }, refreshRate);
  }

  // Client side
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(`
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>SSE</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <pre id="log"></pre>
      </body>
      <script>
        var eventSource = new EventSource('/events');
        eventSource.onmessage = function(event) {
          document.getElementById('log').innerHTML += event.data + '<br>';
        };
      </script>
    </html>
  `);
});

server.listen(port);

server.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log(err);
  process.exit(1);
});

server.on('listening', () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});

Getting output:
curl -N -H "Accept:text/event-stream" --silent http://localhost:3000/events

Tests results
I got no output/ results with:
curl -N -H "Accept:text/event-stream" --silent http://localhost:3000/events | jq -Rs 'match("data:(.*)")|.captures[0].string|fromjson|.summary'

and
curl -N -H "Accept:text/event-stream" --silent http://localhost:3000/events | tr -cd '[:print:]' | sed 's/^data://' | jq '.summary'

Update 2: Output of hexdump -C in combination with curl --no-buffer
curl -N --http2 -H "Accept:text/event-stream" --silent --no-buffer  https://my_domain/stream/OyP1cEC3N7BTQrCsm3AHrTFAj5F5VKCH/notifications | hexdump -C

Will give the following output:
00000000  64 61 74 61 3a 7b 22 69  64 22 3a 22 36 36 66 63  |data:{"id":"66fc|
00000010  64 38 39 65 39 35 65 35  62 31 34 38 66 65 35 63  |d89e95e5b148fe5c|
00000020  37 66 64 32 22 2c 22 73  75 6d 6d 61 72 79 22 3a  |7fd2","summary":|
00000030  22 55 6e 69 6e 76 6f 69  63 65 64 20 61 6d 6f 75  |"Uninvoiced amou|
00000040  6e 74 20 30 2e 33 39 22  2c 22 6c 65 76 65 6c 22  |nt 0.39","level"|
00000050  3a 22 69 6e 66 6f 22 2c  22 64 61 74 65 22 3a 22  |:"info","date":"|
00000060  32 30 32 34 2d 31 30 2d  30 32 54 30 35 3a 32 32  |2024-10-02T05:22|
00000070  3a 33 38 2e 38 37 37 2b  30 30 3a 30 30 22 7d 0a  |:38.877+00:00"}.|


Tangentially, the /g option to the s command in sed only makes sense when you expect multiple occurrences on the same line. In this example, it seems there is always only one, and it's hard to see how there could be more.

Are there any invisible characters in the data? Many web servers emit a DOS carriage return (^M) although it's hard to see how that could play in here.

I have removed the tr from the example, i thought it might be related to new lines why jq fails. But it is not related.

For what it's worth echo also adds a newline, so your multiline example actually has two of them at the end. But jq should tolerate and ignore any number of newlines (though it's weird, and bad practice, to have none at all).

Invisible characters might be the case, I will try this out. Would it be a good idea to substring the json string before running jq (between the brackets, so any weird chars after that are removed?)

input buffering: https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf – you will get output … eventually, once enough data has been written into the pipe

Considering @knittl comment, if you use curl ... --no-buffer ..., what is the behavior then?

try curl -N --http2 -H "Accept:text/event-stream" --silent https://my_domain/stream/OyP1cEC3N7BTQrCsm3AHrTFAj5F5VKCH/notifications | sed 's/data://g | hexdump -C' to see if there are non-printable characters

no buffer did not work for me, same result.

hexdump did not output anything

hexdump did output something when not using the sed command before it. I have posted the results in my question

Update on no buffer: it did do something however, when combined with hexdump -C I saw the completele response from the server appearing, without no buffer, I would see a partial response

Using your NodeJS test server, this works for me:
$ node server.js &
[1] 691108
Listening on port 3000

$ curl -N -H "Accept:text/event-stream" --silent http://localhost:3000/events \
> | jq -R 'scan("^data:(.*)")[] | fromjson.summary'
"Balans: 305.37"
"Balans: 305.37"
"Balans: 305.37"
"Balans: 305.37"
^C


A full jq solution:
curl... | jq -Rs 'match("data:(.*)")|.captures[0].string|fromjson|.summary

In details:

jq --raw-input --slurp handles input as raw string data and captures everything including newlines
match("data:(.*)") Regex match string starting with data: and captures .* everything ongoing after that.
.captures[0].string This contains the captured string that is expected to be raw JSON.
fromjson| Parses the raw JSON into actual JSON data
. .summary outputs the summary entry from the root object


Sorry, it does not work. I have added a test server script in my answer for you to reproduce the results

Try removing non-printable characters
curl ... | tr -cd '[:print:]' | sed 's/^data://' | jq '.summary'

and you should get
"Balans: 305.37"
"Balans: 305.37"
...


Sorry, it does not work. I have added a test server script in my answer for you to reproduce the results
